# Scroll horizontal al agregar video de fondo

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, programación-móvil

espero que me puedan ayudar: tengo un sitio que he ido modificando ya que es una plantilla que tiene html, css y js. Mi problema es que en la vista responsiva se activa un scroll horizontal.

Al inicio de la etiqueta main hay un video de fondo con el que se muestra gracias al siguiente código:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Y en el CSS esta este código:

```
#myVideo {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -1;}
```

Ya agregue scripts y css que en otros proyectos me ayudaron a "desactivar" este scroll horizontal pero no se porque no funciona, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Veo que tienes un min-widht del 100%; si el contenedor que contiene el vídeo no es responsive, esto va a hacer que el vídeo tampoco sea responsive. Igualmente, si tu problema es solamente que se te genera un scroll horizontal, prueba con   overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: Si ya probé con agregar ese css a las etiquetas body, html incluso * pero ninguna funciona ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude, no se porque pero tuve que agregar estilo en linea

```
style=" overflow-x: hidden;"
```

a las etiquetas html y body

Answer (score 0):

Trata de darle las dimensiones al video ajusta lo alto y lo ancho.

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

O si prefieres darle las dimensiones manualmente desde html

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" height="250" height:"500">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: gracias, lamentablemente el problema consiste );